# How to remove file type submenus from the "new" context menu in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm particularly interested in removing the "Java Class" submenu as Kotlin is more relevant to my needs. Although I know you can attach keybindings to controls, this would be convenient for me as I prefer to use my mouse to operate the IDE. Is there any way to do this?

[image: Java Class menu]

I'm using the latest IDE version.

Comment: It would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove it right now, please [vote for this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171273).